# InlineKeyboard and handle_output_submenu_callback not working on my Python Telegram Bot

Tags: python, telegram, chatbot, python-telegram-bot

I just make a simple Telegram Bot that can help student learn about Input and Output definition and devices through Telegram using Python.

The Bot is running well until I click the 'Output' submenu which have 4 different emojis: Monitor, Speaker, Headset and Printer.

When the user click one of those emojis, the Bot should send a message about the definiton of the emoji. For example if the User click Monitor, the Bot will send the definition of Monitor as output device.

It is working properly on the 'Input' submenu, the Bot send the definition and works perfectly. But, the 'Output' just doesn't work. Please help, I'm stuck here for two days.. Thank you. Here's the full code.

---

```
from typing import Final
from telegram import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup
from telegram import Update
from telegram.ext import Application, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, filters, ContextTypes, CallbackContext, CallbackQueryHandler

TOKEN: Final = ''
BOT_USERNAME: Final = ''


# Ini commandsnya.
# /start
async def start_command(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    message_text = "<b>Halo!</b> Botik akan membantumu memahami materi pembelajaran Informatika khususnya tentang Input Output Sistem Komputer.\n\nCommand berikut bisa kamu gunakan agar memudahkan Botik membantu kamu dalam belajar.\n \n<b>Command</b>\n<b>/search</b> - memberikan pilihan sub materi yang mau kamu cari tau\n/<b>help</b> - membantu kamu apabila memiliki kendala saat menggunakan Botik\n<b>/ask</b> - menghubungkan dengan gurumu ketika kamu memiliki pertanyaan lebih lanjut mengenai sub materi yang dipilih"
    await update.message.reply_text(message_text, parse_mode="HTML")

# /search
async def search_command(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    message_text = 'Apa yang mau kamu cari tahu?'
    input_button = InlineKeyboardButton('Input', callback_data='input')
    output_button = InlineKeyboardButton('Output', callback_data='output')
    keyboard = [[input_button, output_button]]
    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
    await update.message.reply_text(message_text, reply_markup=reply_markup)

# Ini untuk jawaban Input
async def handle_input_callback(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    input_message_text = 'Perangkat input adalah perangkat yang digunakan untuk memasukkan data atau informasi ke dalam komputer. Fungsi utama perangkat input adalah untuk mengontrol atau memanipulasi perangkat lunak atau program pada komputer. Jenis-jenis dari perangkat input diantaranya sebagai berikut:'
    emoji_keyboard_input = [
        [InlineKeyboardButton('️', callback_data='mouse'),
         InlineKeyboardButton('⌨️', callback_data='keyboard'),
         InlineKeyboardButton('️', callback_data='joystick'),
         InlineKeyboardButton('', callback_data='microphone')],
    ]
    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(emoji_keyboard_input)
    await update.callback_query.message.reply_text(input_message_text, reply_markup=reply_markup)

# Ini untuk jawaban Output
async def handle_output_callback(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    output_message_text = 'Perangkat output adalah perangkat yang digunakan untuk menampilkan atau mengeluarkan data atau informasi dari komputer. Fungsi utama perangkat output adalah untuk menampilkan hasil pengolahan data atau informasi yang dilakukan oleh komputer. Jenis-jenis dari perangkat output diantaranya sebagai berikut:'
    emoji_keyboard_output = [
        [InlineKeyboardButton('️', callback_data='monitor'),
         InlineKeyboardButton('', callback_data='speaker'),
         InlineKeyboardButton('', callback_data='headset'),
         InlineKeyboardButton('️', callback_data='printer')],
    ]
    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(emoji_keyboard_output)
    await update.callback_query.message.reply_text(output_message_text, reply_markup=reply_markup)

# Ini untuk jawaban submenu Input
async def handle_input_submenu_callback(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    message_texts = {
        'mouse': 'Mouse adalah perangkat input komputer yang digunakan untuk mengontrol posisi kursor di layar dengan gerakan bola kecil atau sensor optik. Tombol-tombol pada mouse juga dapat digunakan untuk melakukan tindakan tertentu pada komputer seperti mengklik atau memindahkan objek di layar. Mouse sangat populer karena mudah digunakan dan dapat mempercepat interaksi pengguna dengan komputer. Saat ini, ada berbagai jenis mouse yang tersedia di pasaran.',
        'keyboard': 'Keyboard adalah perangkat input yang paling umum digunakan pada komputer. Keyboard terdiri dari sejumlah tombol yang digunakan untuk memasukkan karakter, angka, dan simbol ke dalam komputer. Selain itu, keyboard juga dapat digunakan untuk melakukan tindakan tertentu pada komputer seperti mengakses menu dan memindahkan kursor di layar. Saat ini, ada berbagai jenis keyboard yang tersedia di pasaran.',
        'joystick': 'Joystick adalah sebuah alat masukan (input) pada sistem komputer yang umumnya digunakan untuk mengontrol permainan (game) pada komputer atau konsol game. Joystick biasanya terdiri dari sebuah stik yang dapat dimiringkan ke berbagai arah dan beberapa tombol untuk mengeksekusi perintah-perintah pada permainan.',
        'microphone': 'Mikrofon adalah perangkat input yang digunakan untuk merekam suara dan memasukkannya ke dalam komputer dalam format digital. Mikrofon sering digunakan untuk merekam suara pada konferensi, rekaman musik, atau percakapan video. Saat ini, ada berbagai jenis mikrofon yang tersedia di pasaran.'
    }
    callback_data = update.callback_query.data
    if callback_data in message_texts:
        message_text = message_texts[callback_data]
        await update.callback_query.message.reply_text(message_text)

# Ini untuk jawaban submenu Output
async def handle_output_submenu_callback(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    message_texts = {
    'monitor': 'Monitor adalah perangkat output yang digunakan untuk menampilkan informasi atau gambar dari komputer. Monitor biasanya terdiri dari layar datar (flat-screen) yang dapat menampilkan gambar dengan resolusi tinggi.',
    'speaker': 'Speaker adalah perangkat output yang digunakan untuk memainkan suara dari komputer. Speaker biasanya terdiri dari satu atau beberapa unit yang menghasilkan suara dengan kualitas yang baik.',
    'headset': 'Headset adalah perangkat output yang digunakan untuk mendengarkan suara atau musik dari komputer. Headset biasanya terdiri dari sepasang earphone dan mikrofon yang terhubung ke komputer melalui kabel atau teknologi nirkabel.',
    'printer': 'Printer adalah perangkat output yang digunakan untuk mencetak informasi atau gambar dari komputer ke media cetak seperti kertas atau kain. Printer biasanya terdiri dari beberapa komponen seperti toner atau tinta, kertas, dan mekanisme cetak.'
    }
    callback_data = update.callback_query.data
    if callback_data in message_texts:
        message_text = message_texts[callback_data]
        await update.callback_query.message.reply_text(message_text)


# Ini test pesan yang dikirim user.
def handle_response(text: str) -> str:
    processed: str = text.lower()

    if 'tolong' in processed:
        return 'Apa yang bisa kiseki bantu kak?'

    if 'halo' in processed:
        return 'Halo kakak cantik/ganteng.'

    if 'terimakasih' in processed or 'makasih' in processed:
        return 'Sama-sama kak!'

    return 'Maaf kak, kiseki tidak mengerti...'

# Memberikan notifikasi jika ada pesan baru dari user.
async def handle_message(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    message_type: str = update.message.chat.type
    text: str = update.message.text

    print(f'User ({update.message.chat.id}) in {message_type}: "{text}"')

    if message_type == 'group':
        if BOT_USERNAME in text:
            new_text: str = text.replace(BOT_USERNAME, '').strip()
            response: str = handle_response(new_text)
        else:
            return
    else:
        response: str = handle_response(text)

    print('Bot:', response)
    await update.message.reply_text(response)

# Ini jika ada error. 
async def error(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    print(f'Update {update} caused error {context.error}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Memulai bot botik...')
    app = Application.builder().token(TOKEN).build()


    app.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start_command))
    app.add_handler(CommandHandler('search', search_command))
    app.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(handle_input_callback, pattern='input'))
    app.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(handle_output_callback, pattern='output'))
    app.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(handle_input_submenu_callback))
    app.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(handle_output_submenu_callback))
    

    # Ini untuk pesan yang dikirim user
    app.add_handler(MessageHandler(filters.TEXT, handle_message))

    # Ini Errors lagi.
    app.add_error_handler(error)
    # Ini Polling..
    print('Polling bot botik...')
    app.run_polling(poll_interval=5)
```

I tried to change the name of the function, and others. But still doesn't work. I just want to know why it is not working like the 'Input' submenu. The code doesn't even have any erros. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment the first handler `handle_input_submenu_callback` will handle everything and `handle_output_submenu_callback` is never called.

You could use the `pattern=` parameter like you did with `handle_input_callback` to distinguish which one should be called.

Another solution would be to combine `handle_input_submenu_callback` and `handle_output_submenu_callback` into one function that contains both input and output texts.

If you want to use `pattern=` you could add a prefix. For example:

```py
    {
        'input_mouse': '..',
        'input_keyboard':'..',
        'input_joystick':'..',
        'input_microphone': '..',
    }

    {
       'output_monitor': '..',
       'output_speaker': '..',
       'output_headset': '..',
       'output_printer': '..'
    }

# Use a regular expression to match the prefix:
CallbackQueryHandler(handle_input_submenu_callback, pattern=r'input_.*')
CallbackQueryHandler(handle_output_submenu_callback, pattern=r'output_.*')
```